# JavaFX 2 setting the caret position in the table view edit TextField after requesting focus

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-2, javafx

In JavaFX 2 I created a custom TableCell which overrides the startEdit() method to request the focus. So as soon as I invoke the edit command on the cell, the editing text field which appears gets focused.

The next step would be to set the caret position to the end of the text field. But for unknown reasons it doesn't seem to work. It is always placed before the 1st char.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
public void startEdit() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        super.startEdit();
        createTextField();
        setText(null);
        textField.end();
        setGraphic(textField);
        ((TextField)getGraphic()).end();
        textField.end();

        Platform.runLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getGraphic().requestFocus();
                    }
                });
    }
}


public void startEdit() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        super.startEdit();
        createTextField();
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.end();

        Platform.runLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getGraphic().requestFocus();
                        textField.end(); 
                        ((TextField)getGraphic()).end();
                    }
                });
    }
}


public void startEdit() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        super.startEdit();

        createTextField();
        setText(null);
        textField.end();
        setGraphic(textField);
        ((TextField)getGraphic()).end();
        getGraphic().requestFocus();
        ((TextField)getGraphic()).end();
        textField.end();
    }
}
```

The logical approach would be to request focus on the text field, and then move the caret, but it doesn't seem to work for whichever reason.

Maybe someone can enlighten me?

Comment: You should try to add a few more relevant tags to get a bit more exposure

Comment: Is there any text inside the texfield when changing to editing mode? In Platform.runlater try textfield.setText("some text"); and see where the caret is placed.

Comment: @uluk-biy Yes, there is text inside the field when changing to editing mode. When I requestFocus() and setText() afterwards, the caret still is before the 1st char.

Comment: I found out that the methods like positionCaret(), end() and selectAll() only work when you put them inside the Platform.runLater() method and call them after you requestFocus() on the text field. But this somehow does not apply to the text field inside my table cell factory... It still doesn't work there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after trying lots of different things, I finally found the solution.

Don't ask me why, but the problem seems to be caused by creating a new TextField for each edit. If you reuse the existing textfield, it works!

So try this:

```
public void startEdit() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        super.startEdit();

        if (textField == null)
            createTextField();
        else
            textField.setText(getString());

        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);

        Platform.runLater(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textField.requestFocus();
                        textField.deselect(); 
                        textField.end(); 
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Neither of the above answers properly address the problem of cursor positioning in the custom table cell's TextField. If you have found that the above works for you then imho it is more a matter of luck, subject to the race condition of the control having been laid out prior to the cursor being positioned.

You need to modify the GUI component at the correct time in the spirit of the JavaFX framework. i.e. in the controls layoutChildren method. e.g. you need to override the layoutChildren method of the custom TableCell:

```
TextField textField = new TextField() {
    private boolean first = true;

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
      super.layoutChildren();

      // Set cursor caret at end of text (and clear highlighting)
      if (first) {
        this.end();
        first = false;
      }
    }
  };
```

I also note that Java 1.8.0_241 also contains this problem in the TextFieldTableCell implementation. Worse TextField is completely private to the TextFieldTableCell implementation, so in order to work around that I chose to copy the source of javax.scene.table.cell.TextFieldTableCell and javax.scene.table.cell.CellUtils. TextField is instantiated in CellUtils, so you can fix the cursor positioning there. e.g.

```
  static <T> TextField createTextField(final Cell<T> cell, final StringConverter<T> converter) {
    final TextField textField = new TextField(getItemText(cell, converter)) {
    private boolean first = true;

      @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        // Set cursor caret at end of text (and clear highlighting)
        if (first) {
          this.end();
          first = false;
        }
      };
  ...

  ...
  }
```